# Get source code of a functions prototype

Tags: javascript, node.js

Let's say I do the following:

```
String.prototype.myFunc = function(){ /* code here */ }
```

I have just created a new method, `myFunc`, that will be available for each string (`"This is a test".myFunc()`).

My question is: Is it possible, and if it is, how, to get the source code of `myFunc` programatically? (This is inside Node)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can obtain the function as a string using the `toString` method that sits on `Function.prototype`.

`var funcSource = String.prototype.myFunc.toString();`

Comment: Yes indeed. This is exactly what I was looking for :)